# Why Scalar::Util::reftype return `undef` instead of empty string?

Tags: perl

`ref` returns empty string for scalar values.

**Why `Scalar::Util::reftype` return `undef` instead of empty string like `ref` does?**

What is the benefit of `undef`? In compare, the benefit of empty string is less coding while doing:

```
reftype $data eq 'HASH'
```

When `undef` is returned we will get `Use of uninitialized value while eq at ...` and we should do:

```
(reftype($data) //'') eq 'HASH'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right place to ask. [Try the bugtracker?](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=Scalar-List-Utils) Regardless, it's unlikely to change as now it would be a backcompat breakage for no real benefit.

Comment: Why should it return a reftype when the input is not a reference? Seems nonsensical to me, and using undef to indicate the absence of a value seems perfectly fine. Arguably the problem isn't reftype() but how Perl's comparison operators handle undef.

Comment: Obviously it can't change, no. I was looking to ask this myself (but found this question already here)...I was kind of hoping there'd be *some good reason* which I could learn and then it wouldn't bother me much.  Right now, if doing input validation on something that's supposed to be an array ref, I have to remember that the comparison will fail if what's passed in isn't a reference at all, and do the checking in two steps instead of one. I care about "hash ref" vs. "everything else", since the second case gets a carp().

Comment: It should return a value easily checkable, rather than a value hard to check, to indicate that it's not a reference. Having to do the check in two stages is annoying and easily forgotten and many people don't even realize they need to for years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, bad input results in `undef` (if not an exception), which (eventually) results in a warning so that the error can be found.

The most controversial warning is the uninitialized warning because there's no immediate benefit. But when one considers it part of the larger error framework, one realizes it's a key component of Perl's error detection and debugging system. Having functions return undef on bad input is another component of that system.

I dispute your claim that it makes code smaller. For starters, one should never use `reftype` as it breaks Perl's data model. (This is why `keys $ref` was always a bad idea, and never went past the experimental stage.) This means the amount of code in question is quite small.

Still, it can make sense to produce data that requires its use, as long as certain limits are guaranteed. (For example, the output of `decode_json` can requires it's use, and it can be used safely because `decode_json` will never produce objects or magical variables.) When it is needed, a number of checks are usually performed, so returning an empty string doesn't really help.

```
my $type = reftype($val);
if (!defined($type)) { ... }
elsif ($type eq 'HASH') { ... }
elsif ($type eq 'ARRAY') { ... }
...
```

Note that changing `reftype` would breaks this code, so changing `reftype` is not an option. I was going to say you could ask the author for an alternate sub that behaves the way you want, but you could just as easily produce that sub yourself.

Comment: This argument fails to apply, it seems to me, in exactly the place where I most often use reftype -- namely when I'm validating inputs. I expect a hash ref, if I get anything else I'm issuing a carp() or croak() or something. Having that code fail on the undef warning instead makes my error reporting less good, and I have to remember to add extra code in every single case. Well, or just turn off the undef warning; that's probably really the better solution.

Comment: @dd-b You are mistaken. The argument is that it only warns in buggy code, and your code is buggy. Using `reftype` in the circumstance you describe is wrong as it will sometimes give the wrong answer.